# Ember component action not bubbling up to template router

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I have a component that should bubble an action up to its template router.

I pass the name of the action to the component:

```
{{project-table projects=model viewProject="viewProject"}}
```

Inside my component (project-table), I have:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        viewProject: function (project) {
            this.sendAction('viewProject', project);
        }
    }
});
```

Inside the component template, I have:

```
<button type="button" {{action "viewProject" project}}>
    My Button
</button>
```

Last but not least, I have my router:

```
actions: {
     viewProject: function (project) {
         this.transitionToRoute('project', project);
     }
}
```

The component's action gets invoked correctly. However from there on, the action does not bubble up. Any ideas as to what I might be going wrong?

Comment: not sure if this is a typo, but your project-table controller is extending Ember.Component, so it's not a controller.

Comment: Can you give different names to your actions?

Comment: Is `project-table` inside another component?

Comment: Do you mean route?

Comment: @PeterBrown Yes, thanks. Fixed typo.

Comment: @locks: No, it isn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JB2, your code is almost perfect, and I'm sure that the action is bubble up to the Route level.

However, please note, that **Route** has `transitionTo` method only. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo

In a **Controller**, you can use `transitionToRoute` method.
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

It is easy to mix. :) I check the API doc also quite often, which one could I use and where. :)

Comment: Thank you Zoltan. Yes, that was it! :-) Uff, the amount of time I spent on this haha. Thank you!!